# python: how to check Windows folder listdir(List Folder Contents) permission?

Tags: python, windows, permissions

We need to check whether the current Windows account has `listdir/[List Folder Contents][1]` permisison to a windows folder.  currently we're using `os.access(path, os.R_OK)`. however, from my understanding, a windows user can have read access to a folder without `List folder Conents` permission.

**my test:**
create a fodler, config `Security`, deny `List folder / read data` permission.

when I access it in windows file explorer, `You don't currently have permission to access this folder` -- this is what I'm expecting.  however, when I test in python:

```
>>> p = r'c:\tmp\p'
>>> os.stat(p)
 nt.stat_result(st_mode=16895, st_ino=0L, st_dev=0L, st_nlink=0, st_uid=0, st_gid=0, st_size=0L, st_a
time=1463736204L, st_mtime=1463736204L, st_ctime=1463736135L)
>>> os.access(p, os.R_OK)
True
>>> os.listdir(p)
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
 WindowsError: [Error 5] Access is denied: 'c:\\tmp\\p/*.*'
```

os.access => True; os.list => Exception

**question**

I dont think `os.access()` is a proper funciton to test the `List Folder Conents` permission, is there any other funciton/lib in Python can check the  listdir(List Folder Contents) permission?

understand that `It's easier to ask for forgiveness than for permission`, but I still want to find a proper way to verify the listdir permission.  thanks!

Comment: It's recommended to try the operation and handle any exceptions. So there hasn't been a pressing need to enhance `os.access` on Windows to do a proper WinAPI `AccessCheck`. As is, `os.access` only checks the read-only file attribute, which isn't useful to you. If a proper check were implemented, then testing `os.R_OK` would be correct. The right to list a folder is the same as the right to read data.

Comment: You could use subprocess to run [accesschk.exe](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/accesschk.aspx) to check access for the current user. For example: `user = os.environ['USERNAME'];` `out = subprocess.check_output('accesschk -qdv "%s" "%s"' % (user, path));` `list_access = any(x in out for x in [b'FILE_ALL_ACCESS', b'FILE_LIST_DIRECTORY'])`.

Answer (score 0):

try using: os.listdir(), it would make a ls on the command line of the current directory, however, the ls would be in array format, use it like this:

```
import os
ls = os.listdir()
print(ls)
```

did this answer your question?